# velocity question from book iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am reading an iphone game dev book and I have a question about velocity.

mainly it is this line

```
playerVelocity = ccp(playerVelocity.x * dec + acceleration.x * sens, 0);
```

Why do you mutiple the playerVelocity.x by the deceleration. the book says it works by reducing the current velocity so it is easier to change direction and then add the ( acceleration.x * sens. )

this piece of code is using the accelerometer.

```
float dec = 0.4f; //lower = quicker to change direction;
float sens = 6.0f; //higher more sensitive;
float maxVel = 100;

playerVelocity = ccp(playerVelocity.x * dec + acceleration.x * sens, 0);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(playerVelocity));

if(playerVelocity.x > maxVel)
{
    playerVelocity.x = maxVel;
}
else if(playerVelocity.x < - maxVel)
{
    playerVelocity.x = - maxVel;
}
```

Comment: Without the deceleration, your player-entity will never get slower without any further input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by acceleration I think you are referring to the value IPhone accecelometer returns.

dec value may be used for two reasons :

1. to simulate friction.
2. to make velocity changes more smooth.

dec value also creates some upper and lower bounds for player velocity. note that if `-1 < acceleration.x < 1` we can assume velocity should be somewhere between -10 and 10.

for more information I need to know the code other than that lines.

Comment: modified my question for you to include some more info. the playerVelocity.x < - maxVel line i also dont understand, is that less than negative maxVel? surely it should be playerVelocity < maxVel.

Comment: that part doesn't really make any difference, that's just a more strick bounds for velocity.

Comment: @Mintuz You are confusing "velocity" with "speed".  Velocity has a direction, speed does not.  `maxVel` means the max speed in one direction, probably to the right, and `-maxVel` means the max speed in the *opposite* direction.  In other words, the maximum velocity you can go to the left is the same as the maximum velocity you can go to the right.

Comment: @matthew: check his code velocity.y is always 0, so there is no difference between speed and velocity here (assuming speed is a signed value).

Comment: Speed is never a signed value.  Speed begins at 0 (no motion) and increases (with motion).  Negative speed doesn't make sense, since you can only *move*, not "anti-move".  Velocity, however, has a direction.  Negative just means opposite when used with a direction, so negative velocity is possible.  Negative velocity rightward is the same as positive velocity leftward.  The lack of velocity up or down doesn't matter.

Comment: @matthew sorry about my last sentence (I just like to assume speed can be negetive too) but in his question there is y value is always zero so there is only 1D velocity and that means those 2 if statesments are bound for the velocity (and also speed).

Comment: thankyou everybody for ur help. I think i understand it now. Velocity.y is set to 0 because the character can only move left and right and not up and down.